# Vaadin, Spring Boot, Microsoft Graph - How can I extend the acces token with the refresh token

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, vaadin, refresh-token

I am developing an application that accesses Microsoft Graph and everything works fine so far. But after an hour the access token has expired and I do not understand how I can refresh the token. I researched a lot and nothing seems to fit to the approach with azure spring boot starter. It would be really nice if someone has a tip because I was not able to find something helpful in the Microsoft documentation or anywhere else.

As far as I am understanding this, I have to send a new Post request with the refresh_token to get a new access token. But how can I do this in this scenario?

I am using Vaadin 14.7, here are the other libraries:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>  
  <version>2.5.5</version> 
</dependency>  

<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
</dependency>  

<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
  <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>  
  <version>3.9.0</version> 
</dependency>  

<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>  
  <version>5.5.2</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>  
  <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>  
  <version>5.4.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

This is my code to get the GraphServiceClient to make requests against the Graph API

```
public GraphServiceClient<Request> getGraphService() throws OAuthTokenException {
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken token;
    try {
        token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new OAuthTokenException("Token cannot be cast");
    }

    if (token == null)
        throw new OAuthTokenException("No valid OAuth Token");

    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(
            token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(),
            (HttpServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest());

    return GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new GraphAuthenticationProvider(authorizedClient))
            .buildClient();
}
```

The Authentication Provider:

```
public class GraphAuthenticationProvider extends BaseAuthenticationProvider {
private final OAuth2AuthorizedClient graphAuthorizedClient;

/**
 * Set up the GraphAuthenticationProvider. Allows accessToken to be
 * used by GraphServiceClient through the interface IAuthenticationProvider
 *
 * @param graphAuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient created by AAD Boot starter. Used to surface the access token.
 */
public GraphAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2AuthorizedClient graphAuthorizedClient) throws OAuthTokenException {
    if (graphAuthorizedClient == null)
        throw new OAuthTokenException("No valid client!");

    this.graphAuthorizedClient = graphAuthorizedClient;
}

/**
 * This implementation of the IAuthenticationProvider helps injects the Graph access
 * token into the headers of the request that GraphServiceClient makes.
 *
 * @param requestUrl the outgoing request URL
 * @return a future with the token
 */
@Override
public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(final URL requestUrl){
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(graphAuthorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
}
```

}

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Lazy
@Autowired
private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login**", "/error**", "/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
}

...

@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use refresh_token to refresh old token , below steps can be help to get the refresh token, please refer the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token) .
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have already seen this documentation, but I thought it is not for my use case. For me, it seems a bit strange that I have to do this manually and there is no API call for this, like for every other request I do against the graph API. But I will definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in your code the graph version is old , so try to you update the version to 5.17.0 firs,please follow the docs - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java
[image]

Then we recommend you to use MSAL for authentication , docs https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java ,
[image]

and then try to acquire the token - refer [docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens#msal4j-caches-tokens) , [image]